# In category theory, how do you model substituting a variable in a function for another function?

Tags: category-theory, substitution

Say you have a function $f(x,y)$ and another function $z(y)$, which you can easily transform into $y(z)$, by solving for $y$. Then, by substituting $y$ with $y(z)$ into $f(x,y)$, you can easily construct another function $f(x,z)$, but how would one model this in category theory?

Could this be related? http://math.andrej.com/2012/09/28/substitution-is-pullback/

I'm just trying to understand what my economy professor *really* means when he says that maximizing utility and minimizing expenditure is a *dual* problem. I want to build a category, flip de arrows and verify that indeed they are dual.

Comment: I think he just meant that it is two problems. Maybe there's something you can do here though, I don't know.

Comment: I think he is using a more informal sense of the word dual.

Comment: He almost certainly means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)). This is probably better thought of in relation to dual orders/lattices.  You could connect those orders to categories, but this would probably not be clarifying.  Specific pages that may help understanding where the "dual" comes from: [Dual pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair), [Perturbation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_function), [Convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Order_reversing)

Comment: It is incredibly unlikely that the word "dual" in this context has anything to do with category theory...